# Drop shadow with fade in animation is cut off on iOS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a website where I fade in a set of SVG icons which have the `filter: drop-shadow` rule applied. This works fine on desktop, however on iOS the shadow gets cut off once the animation finishes.

For example, this is the html:

```html
<div class="fade-in">
  <svg class="shadow" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The css:

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fade-in 2s;
}

.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.1rem 0.7rem black);
}
```

JS Bin:
https://jsbin.com/yonifusomo/edit?html,css,output

Result on iOS after the animation finishes:

[image: Broken shadow on iOS after animation finishes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari has multiple bugs related to shadows and various animations. Luckily, looks like this one is not the worst. Adding a `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` property to your `.fade-in` class did the trick for me.

For more info: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496495/text-shadow-in-safari-getting-cut-off-not-rendering-beyond-element-border) is pretty similar to yours, and it contains almost same advice.

Comment: Seems like a hacky solution, though it does the job! Thank you

Comment: Looks hacky to me too, although since it's a bug in a browser which is known to exist for a while already I don't kind of feel ashamed of using a workaround ;) Glad it worked.